# static const variable inside a class used as template

Tags: c++, templates

I have a problem using a class which has some `static const` variables as a template for a templated class.
This my normal class (Just a `header` file):

```
class NoBoundsChecking
{
public:
    static const size_t sizeFront = 0;
    static const size_t sizeBack = 0;

    inline void guardFront() const {};
};
```

This is how i want to use it (also a `header` file):

```
template<class BoundsCheckingPolicy>
class MemoryArena
{
public:

    MemoryArena()
    {
    }

    void* allocate(size_t size, size_t alignment, int line, char* file)
    {
        size_t boundedSize = m_boundsGuard::sizeFront + size + m_boundsGuard::sizeBack;
        m_boundsGuard.guardFront();
    }

private:
    BoundsCheckingPolicy    m_boundsGuard;
};
```

This works fine: `m_boundsGuard.guardFront();`
But this `m_boundsGuard::sizeFront` gives me errors. 
Here is the complete error:

```
error C2653: 'm_boundsGuard' : is not a class or namespace name
1>e:\...\memorymanager.h(102) : while compiling class template member function 'void *MemoryArena<NoBoundsChecking>::allocate(size_t,size_t,int,char *)'
1>e:\...\main.cpp(21) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void *MemoryArena<NoBoundsChecking>::allocate(size_t,size_t,int,char *)' being compiled
1>e:\...\main.cpp(19) : see reference to class template instantiation 'MemoryArena<NoBoundsChecking>' being compiled
1>e:\...\memorymanager.h(111): error C2065: 'sizeFront' : undeclared identifier
```

Comment: have you defined both static variables...

Comment: Yes. Take a look at the `NoBoundsChecking` class.

Comment: instead of `m_boundsGuard::sizeFront` use `BoundsCheckingPolicy::sizeFront` or `m_boundsGuard.sizeFront`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`m_boundsGuard` is not class or namespace. Correct versions are:

```
// Using dot
size_t boundedSize = m_boundsGuard.sizeFront + size + m_boundsGuard.sizeBack;

// Using class
size_t boundedSize = BoundsCheckingPolicy::sizeFront + size + BoundsCheckingPolicy::sizeBack;
```

Comment: Oh my god. How could i not see this. Thanks a lot both of u who answered. I will mark your answer as correct one as soon as possible, because u were first!

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access static members via an object, rather than the class. Try this:

```
size_t boundedSize = BoundsCheckingPolicy::sizeFront + size + BoundsCheckingPolicy::sizeBack;
```